Geometric interpretation of a theorem about localizations of Noetherian normal domain
Recall that a normal domain is an integral domain which is integrally closed in its field of fractions. In Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry, he proves that if $A$ is a Noetherian normal domain, then for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$ of height one, the localization $A_\mathfrak p$ is a discrete valuation ring [Theorem 11.2, page 250]. One page earlier he states that the geometric interpretation of this theorem is that a normal variety $X$ is nonsingular in codimension one, i.e. the singular locus of $X$ has codimension $\ge2$. How does one translate the algebraic statement of the theorem to the geometric one?

Well, additional work is necessary, but it's standard. Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4961412/show-that-a-geometrically-normal-scheme-of-finite-type-has-singular-locus-of-cod and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282937/set-of-singular-points-of-a-normal-variety

@MartinBrandenburg: Thank you for those links. Ideally, I'd like to see an answer that is written in the language of classical algebraic geometry rather than schemes (since I don't know scheme theory). I see that your second link does this, but unfortunately I don't really understand the arguments there. I was hoping to see an answer that just uses the elementary definition of dimension in terms of ascending chains of irreducible closed sets (but perhaps this was too optimistic).

That's okay. Please clarify in your post what you need precisely.
